# Trying to call a function in a .js file from an "onclick" event in my index.html, get an error

Tags: javascript, button

I kept getting format errors in stackoverflow.com when I typed my code, so I took a picture.  Thanks for any assistance.

And now I can't add an image either because stack overflow says I need a 10 reputation.  This is frustrating...

Comment: happens to alot of first timers on here including me.. what u need to do is add 2 blank lines from the top of any text in your question and indent all your code by at least 4 spaces. Then when you paste your code in this format, it will appear properly